# log4j for Alfresco Repository AMP

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, alfresco

How to use log4j for Alfresco Repository AMP?

I gave it a try but nothing land in catalina.out nor alfresco.log.

I think that I have to add some configurations to my log4j.properties file :

```
/content-repo/src/main/amp/config/alfresco/module/content-repo/log4j.properties
```

I m developing a Java-backed repo-tier WebScript and using the integration-test -Pamp-to-war command for alfresco maven sdk version 2.1.0.

Comment: Where does that file end up in the AMP, and when installed?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to debug/log?

Have you tried having a look here:

[Alfresco Developer Series Tutorial - Maven-SDK](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/maven-sdk/tutorial/tutorial.html#logging)

The document is pretty comprehensive on how to log your module extensions in Alfresco.

If you're trying to debug repository-tier server-side web scripts this is usually the entry you want to update:

`log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.jscript.ScriptLogger=debug`

and then use it within your web scripts as follows:

`logger.log("Log me");`

Another useful link is here:

[Alfresco JS logging](http://jmuras.com/blog/index.html%3Fp=1302.html)

If neither of these link helps you, you should probably update your question with some additional info like:

- what extension are you developing (repo-tier or share-tier)
- what artifact are you developing against (alfresco, share or all-in-one?)
- which Alfresco Maven-SDK version are you using
- what exactly are you trying to log/debug

Cheers